# How to sort and select pandas data

Tags: python, pandas

I am brand new to pandas so please excuse how basic this question is. I have a CSV file which I read with

```
df = pandas.read_csv("file.csv")
```

I would like to perform some basic functions now on the data. For example

- Sort by column 11 divided by column 8.
- Select only those records with a particular string contained in field 6.

How can you do that?

Some example data:

```
931,Oxfordshire,9314125,123255,Larkmead School,Abingdon,125,124,20,SUPP,8
931,Oxfordshire,9314126,123256,John Mason School,Abingdon,164,164,25,6,16
931,Oxfordshire,9314127,123257,Fitzharrys School,Abingdon,150,149,9,0,11
```

By deleting the first few rows of comments in the CSV file and then

```
df = pandas.read_csv("GCSEIGCSEresultsv2.csv", header=None, names=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G', 'H','I','J'])
```

I get

```
df.dtypes
Out[20]: 
A    object
B     int64
C     int64
D    object
E    object
F    object
G    object
H    object
I    object
J    object
dtype: object
```

I need to tell pandas that SUPP means NaN I think.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You'll also want to show what your csv file looks like and show your expected output.

Comment: I would encourage you to read the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) and come back with at least an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: @Anush I think you need to try something first and come back with a specific issues rather than ask for the solution, this is pretty basic

Comment: @Anush you can pass a list of names to `read_csv` like so `df = pd.read_csv("file_csv", header=None, names=['col1', 'col2'])`, or just rename after loading `df.columns = my_col_names`

Comment: @EdChum Thanks. How do I tell pandas that SUPP means Nan?

Comment: This is quickly becoming too meandering to be a good question, but the documentation for `read_csv` explains the `na_values` argument.

Comment: I agree with @DSM there is too much basic usage you do not understand at this stage, most of which is explained on the excellent website or book or online video talks. I suggest look at the vids and the online docs, try some stuff and get back to us with more specific issues

Comment: You despair too quickly :) Problem solved now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose I name your columns from `c1` to `c11`:

```
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11
931,Oxfordshire,9314125,123255,Larkmead School,Abingdon,125,124,20,SUPP,8
931,Oxfordshire,9314126,123256,John Mason School,Abingdon,164,164,25,6,16
931,Oxfordshire,9314127,123257,Fitzharrys School,Abingdon,150,149,9,0,11
```

to sort:

```
df['r_c8c11']=df['c11']*1.0/df['c8'] #if your dtype for these columns are int
df.sort(columns=['r_c8c11'])
```

to select only those records with a particular string contained in field 6:

```
df[df['c6']=='Abingdon']
```

Comment: Thank you. With df = pandas.read_csv("file.csv", header=None, names=['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7', 'c8','c9','c10','c11'], na_values='SUPP') this worked perfectly.

Comment: Sure, I was just wondering that you might already have the columns named in the real data in the first place, such as '`Zipcode`,`County`,`School`,`Town`' etc. (It may be a good idea to have the header defined anyway, it improves human-readability). Cheers!